# double conditions don't work in c++

Tags: c++

First: I'm begginer. :) I've got a problem with my c++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    do {
        cout << "a= ";
        cin >> a;
        if (a<=0) {
            cout << "This number is not positive!\n";
        }
    }
    while (a<=0);
    do {
        cout << "b= ";
        cin >> b;
        if (b<=0) {
            cout << "This number is not positive!\n";
        }
    }
    while ((a==b) and (b<=0));
}
```

Have you got any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use && instead of "and"

Comment: How can it be possible that `a == b` *and* `b <= 0` since we already know that `a` is not `<= 0`.

Comment: @EricFortin `and` is a legal replacement for `&&`.

Comment: @jrok Since when ? Can you point me to a reference ? I've never seen that.

Comment: @EricFortin: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and

Comment: @EricFortin: Since C++98 (at least). See C++11 2.6 (and probably the same paragraph in earlier standards, but I don't have them available at the moment).

Comment: Wow, thanks. Never stop learning ...

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `and`. Although `and` is legal C++, it is not idiomatic C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible for that condition to be true. We already know that `a` is positive, so it can't both equal `b` and `b` be negative.

Sounds to me like you want `or` instead. This would mean that `b` also has to be positive and must not be the same as `a`. Note that it is typical to use `&&` instead of `and` and `||` instead of `or`:

```
while ((a==b) || (b<=0));
```

Think about it like this: we can't to continue asking for `b` if they input is negative *or* if the input is the same as `a`.